# Update function value in object array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How would I get a randomly generated value in an object array to regenerate each time it is accessed? For example the following code assigns the random value on page load, how would I get it to update each time it's accessed?

```
const values = [
  { name: "john", favouriteColor: getRandomColor() },
  { name: "tom", favouriteColor: colors[5] },
]
```

```
{displayColor ? <p>Favourite color is {values[0].favouriteColor}</p> : ""}
<button onClick={toggleDisplayColor}>Favourite Color</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [getter on the property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). Everytime it's accessed it will return a random color.

```js
const values = [{
    name: "john",
    get favouriteColor() {return favColor()}
  },
  {
    name: "tom",
    favouriteColor: 'white'
  },
]

function favColor() {
  return `${~~(Math.random()*255)}, ${~~(Math.random()*255)}, ${~~(Math.random()*255)}`
}

document.querySelector("#fav-color").textContent = values[0].favouriteColor;
document.querySelector("#fav-color-2").textContent = values[1].favouriteColor;
```

```html
<p>Favourite random color is <span id="fav-color"></span></p>
<p>Favourite color is <span id="fav-color-2"></span></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Not too familiar with getters but this does seem a bit more performant than using a function to update the array each time it's accessed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a function instead:

```js
function getValues() {
  return [
    { name: "john", favouriteColor: getRandomColor() },
    { name: "tom", favouriteColor: colors[5] },
  ];
}
```

And your example would be

```js
{displayColor ? <p>Favourite color is {getValues()[0].favouriteColor}</p> : ""}
<button onClick={toggleDisplayColor}>Favourite Color</button>
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks! I was hoping it would be something simple like that. Makes total sense.

Comment: Thank you :) I'm happy I could help you.